# Printing from the function to be minimized in FindMinimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, monitoring

I know that there is an option `EvaluationMonitor` for various numerical computation and plotting functions.

But I am curious, why a simple `Print` statement in the function to be minimized does not print. Consider this example:

```
Clear[x, y, z];
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := (Print[
    "in function f called with these arguments: ", {x, y, z}]; 
   1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
FindMinimum[f[{x, y, z}], {{x, 1}, {y, 22}, {z, -3}}]
```

> in function f called with these arguments: {x,y,z}
>
> ```
> {1., {x -> 0., y -> 0., z -> 0.}}
> ```

The result is OK. But I would have expected the first print output to have been

> in function f called with these arguments: {1,22,-3}

**Did I get that completely wrong?**
**Or is `FindMinimum` using some fancy Compiled feature defeating the `Print` statement?**

Comment: May be because of this? `FindMinimum first localizes the values of all variables, then evaluates f with the variables being symbolic, and then repeatedly evaluates the result numerically` so you are looking at first call of the function? You could use `StepMonitor` to see the steps.

Comment: Mathematica does not need to evaluate f numerically to find the minimum. It can do it analytically. Try adding a ?NumericQ to force numeric evaluation.

Comment: @mikado I thought about this first, but the result returned is numerical (i.e. real). it has decimals on it. So it must have used numerical method.

Comment: @nasser Mathematica will do symbolic analysis before attempting to solve the problem numerically and may then minimise the simplified expression  (rather than the original f)

Answer (score 4):

The essence of the problem is already explained by [mikado](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36788/mikado) in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126002/printing-from-the-function-to-be-minimized-in-findminimum#comment341039_126002):

> *Mathematica* will do symbolic analysis before attempting to solve the
>   problem numerically and may then minimize the simplified expression
>   (rather than the original `f`)

One solution is to prevent symbolic analysis of the function by turning it into a *black-box* function:

```
Clear[f, x, y, z];
f[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}] := (Print[
    "in function f called with these arguments: ", {x, y, z}];
   1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
FindMinimum[f[{x, y, z}], {{x, 1}, {y, 22}, {z, -3}}]
```

But it is recommended don't do this when it isn't strictly necessary, and instead use `EvaluationMonitor` for obtaining the evaluation points:

```
Clear[x, y, z, f];
f[{x_, y_, z_}] := (Print["in function f called with these arguments: ", {x, y, z}];
                    1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
FindMinimum[f[{x, y, z}], {{x, 1}, {y, 22}, {z, -3}}, 
            EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{x, y, z}]]
```

If you compare the evaluation points taken with the two above approaches, you will see that in the second case the minimum is found in 2 evaluations of the objective functions (and it is *exact* minimum!), while in the first case much more points are taken and the minimum isn't exact. The explanation is given above by [mikado](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/36788/mikado): symbolic analysis may allow to get the minimum without searching at all. See also the [comment by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126002/printing-from-the-function-to-be-minimized-in-findminimum/126014?noredirect=1#comment341159_126014) under this answer.

Comment: Alexey, after 
Clear[f, x, y, z]; 
f[{x_NumericQ, y_NumericQ, z_NumericQ}] := (Print["in function f called with these arguments: ", {x, y, z}]; 1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2);
FindMinimum claims "The function value f[{1.,22.,-3.}] is not a real number at {x,y,z} = {1.,22.,-3.}." 
The function f applied to these arguments evaluates to itself! Did I get something wrong with your answer?

Comment: Alexey, after removing the NumericQ after the parameters and adding EvaluationMonitor according to your hint, I see tht in this special case the minimum really is found in a single step. If I change my example to 1 + x (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 3.3)^2), it takes three steps according to EvaluationMonitor, but Print just leaves a single "in function f called with these arguments: {x,y,z}". Mikado's argument seems to be right.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen To your first comment: you have removed the `?` before `NumericQ` - that's why it doesn't work. Please copy the code from my answer without editing, it works just fine!

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen When `f[{x, y, z}]` evaluates to an expression that can be symbolically differentiated, `FindMinimum` will use the symbolic derivative for [Newton's method](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodMinimum.html).  For a quadratic function, the derivative is linear, and the problem turns into an exact, one-step, linear algebra problem.  When `f[{x, y, z}]` remains unevalauted (the `?NumericQ` case), then it will numerically approximate the gradient, and the slight numerical error may lead to extra steps to converge.

Comment: Tanks to all. This was a good learning lesson. Yes, with the question mark before the NumericQ, i.e. f[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}] := (Print["in function f called with these arguments: ", {x, y, z}]; 1 + x (x - 1)^2 + (y + 2)^2 + (z - 3.3)^2); the print commands work. The same applies for ListPlot which sometimes is helpfull to see how numerical approximations improve the result.