# How to use constraint condition in FindMinimum?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I wrote a complex constraint condition for my problem.
I have a simple version of my code:

```
c[x_] := If[x >= 20, True, False];
FindMinimum[{x^2, c[x] == True}, x]
NMinimize[{x^2, c[x] == True}, x]
```

Functions `FindMinimum` and `NMinmize` didn't work. I can't see why?

---

**Update**

```
c[x_] := If[x >= 20, True, False];
FindMinimum[{x^2, c[x] }, x]
NMinimize[{x^2, c[x] }, x]
```

It works well, but I can't still solve my problem.
I constructed another example:

```
c[x_] := Module[{}, Print[x]; True];
FindMinimum[{x^2, c[x]}, x]
NMinimize[{x^2, c[x]}, x]

x
{0., {x -> 0.}}
```

Why `Print[x]` didn't output the value of `x`?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov this is just an example. Actually I want a much more complex constraint condition which must be an `Module`

Comment: `Print[x]` didn't output the value of `x` because `x` had no value at the time `Print[x]` was evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `FindMinimum[{x^2, x >= 20}, x]`. Or if you insist on a function,

```
Clear[c]
c[x_] := If[x >= 20, True, False];
FindMinimum[{x^2, c[x]}, x]
NMinimize[{x^2, c[x]}, x]
```

> ```
> {400., {x -> 20.}}
>
> {400., {x -> 20.}}
> ```

For printing intermediate numerical values it is recommended to use `EvaluationMonitor`:

```
FindMinimum[{x^2, c[x]}, x, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]]
NMinimize[{x^2, c[x]}, x, EvaluationMonitor :> Print[x]]
```

Comment: In my example this work well, but my problem is still can't be solved. I update my post

Comment: @YuhengHuang Regarding your **Update**: you problem is very similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126002/280) and is explained in [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126002/printing-from-the-function-to-be-minimized-in-findminimum#comment341039_126002). But the solution is different: use `EvaluationMonitor` for printing intermediate numerical values. Updated the answer.