# How can I store interim results from FindMinimum?

Tags: functions

I wrote a mathematica function which uses external programs. The external programs read numerical datas from mathematica. The mathematica function need x-parameter in the next round of FindMininimum-loop.

```
`myFunction [x_] := Module[{}, 
hugo = DoSomethingwith[x];
Export[hugo];
RunExternalProgram[hugo];
ReadResult[result];
Return[result];]`
```

I know there is an option called EvaluationsMonitor, but I guess it isn't helpful for my problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  How does `FindMinumum` fit into this?

Comment: FindMinimum[myFunction[x],{x,xInitial, x0, xMax}]

Comment: (Please remember to ping me with @jjc385 when you reply to my comment.)  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is -- why is `FindMinimum[myFunction[x],{x,xInitial, x0, xMax}]` not sufficient?  (A minimal working example might help.  If it's not absolutely essential that an external program must be run to illustrate your problem, you could just do it all in mathematica.)

Comment: @jjc385 Thanks a lot. I found a solution for my problem:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126002/printing-from-the-function-to-be-minimized-in-findminimum